# What are these two types of Gibbs sampling LDA called, respectively?

Tags: python, lda, topic-modeling

When learning and implementing LDA with Gibbs sampling, I find that there are two ways of doing it. I wonder if both of them are valid/correct, and if so what they are called respectively.

The first way is updating z fully based on the count, and only updating Phi and Theta at the end of the calculation. I find this method more common.
[image]

Another way, which I personally prefer, is to update Phi and Theta at every change of z. This method will increase the computation time, but will make sure that each update on z is still in Dirichlet distribution, and thus making the procedure more stable even for shorter texts. Below is an extract of my python implementation of this method:

```
for it in range(iterations):
    for d in range(n_d):
        for xi in range(len(X[d])): 
            Z[d][xi] = [0] * n_t    # set the entry we are updating to zeros
            Theta = dist_gen.update_Theta(Z, Theta, alpha)  # Update Theta
            Phi = dist_gen.update_Phi(Z, Phi, X, beta)      # Update Phi

            # Get the distribution of this word in this document
            w, count = X[d][xi]
            p_dw = np.exp(np.log(Theta[d]) + np.log(Phi[:, w]))
            p_dw /= np.sum(p_dw)
            
            # Update z based on the distribution
            assigned_topics = np.random.multinomial(count, p_dw)
            Z[d][xi] = assigned_topics.tolist()

# Do it again in the end
Theta = dist_gen.update_Theta(Z, Theta, alpha)
Phi = dist_gen.update_Phi(Z, Phi, X, beta)
```

Is the second way an established method? What is it called?

Comment: Hi @BoyuanJackChen, have been able to solve the collapsed Gibbs sampler question you had up? Your code helped me a lot (especially the example) and I was able to fix the implementation, let me know if you still need to code, happy to share :)

Comment: I think the main difference here is that by updating phi and theta and using a multinomial distribution you are doing maximum likelihood, not Gibbs sampling

Comment: Thanks Emily. You are right - the function I'm calling is like updating the whole distribution parameters once again, and it's not exactly Gibbs sampling. I understand it now.